# Can't print elements in a DIV tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a Drag-able and re-sizeable DIV's in this HTML file. Where the user will place the DIV tag to his desired place in a main parent DIV tag. Now I want to print this main DIV tag, but the problem is that the code which I'm using to PRINT this main DIV is printing in a sequence, like not the way user has arranged the DIV's. Also it doesn't take up  the main DIV background IMAGE.
here is the code.

JAVASCRIPT & CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="byrei-dyndiv_0.5.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="byrei-dyndiv_1.0rc1.js"></script>   
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function change(boxid,divtoaffect) { 
content = document.getElementById("" + boxid + "").value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'); 
document.getElementById(divtoaffect).innerHTML = content; 
} 
function select1() {
test=document.getElementById("changeMe");
test.style.backgroundImage="url('Sunset.jpg')";
}

function select2() {
test=document.getElementById("changeMe");
test.style.backgroundImage="url('Blue hills.jpg')";
}


    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).text());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.print();
        return true;
    }  

//  Print DIV

function printContent(id){
                            str=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
                            newwin=window.open('','printwin','left=100,top=100,width=400,height=400')
                            newwin.document.write('<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n')
                            newwin.document.write('<TITLE>Print Page</TITLE>\n')
                            newwin.document.write('<script>\n')
                            newwin.document.write('function chkstate(){\n')
                            newwin.document.write('if(document.readyState=="complete"){\n')
                            newwin.document.write('window.close()\n')
                            newwin.document.write('}\n')
                            newwin.document.write('else{\n')
                            newwin.document.write('setTimeout("chkstate()",2000)\n')
                            newwin.document.write('}\n')
                            newwin.document.write('}\n')
                            newwin.document.write('function print_win(){\n')
                            newwin.document.write('window.print();\n')
                            newwin.document.write('chkstate();\n')
                            newwin.document.write('}\n')
                            newwin.document.write('<\/script>\n')
                            newwin.document.write('</HEAD>\n')
                            newwin.document.write('<BODY onload="print_win()">\n')
                            newwin.document.write(str)
                            newwin.document.write('</BODY>\n')
                            newwin.document.write('</HTML>\n')
                            newwin.document.close()
                        }

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<style type="text/css">
#output1,#output2 ,#output3 {
width: 300px;
word-wrap: break-word;
border: solid 1px black;
}



</style>
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:650px;height:300px;" id="changeMe" >

        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin:auto;">
            <tr>
                <td><div class="dynDiv_moveDiv" id="output1" style="font-weight:bold;height:20px;margin-top:40px;">
                    <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_tl"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_tr"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_bl"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_br"></div>
                    </div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="dynDiv_moveDiv" id="output2" style="height:40px;margin-top:30px;">
                    <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_tl"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_tr"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_bl"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_br"></div>
                    </div></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td><div class="dynDiv_moveDiv" id="output3" style="height:50px;margin-top:40px;">
                    <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_tl"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_tr"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_bl"></div>
                     <div class="dynDiv_resizeDiv_br"></div>
                    </div></td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </div>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Print Div" onClick="printContent('changeMe')" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

here is the image to be more clearer 
[image]
[image]

Comment: By default, background images are not printed. Also, so much code... it would be helpful if you could make a JSFiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @Utkanos I'm new to JSFIDDLE I could edit on this much in it can you help , how do I go about it...http://jsfiddle.net/JpUuk/

Comment: @Utkanos PLS see the images that I have uploaded .....

Comment: HTML and CSS don't "pretty print" very well and what you get after extensive effort is... Sad. So you really need to think about shipping your user's settings back to the server, create an image/PDF, and send back the reference to it on the server (ie, URL). `canvas` *may* help if you do the layout in the `canvas` element and then output the `canvas` as an `img` in `base64` and print that element. *May*... And `canvas` is not supported in IE9 and lower.

Comment: We had this issue at my old company. To echo what people have said, background images by default are not printed and CSS doesn't get handled well. The doc gets prepared for what the driver (I'm guessing) assumes is best for straight reading in black and white on 8.5x11 sheets of paper. So it basically defaults to "No Style." The user can sometimes change their preference to print the page "as is" but this isn't the default (and horizontal screen usually gets chopped up undesirably onto the the vertical paper).

Comment: @JaredFarrish is there any other way of doing it..Seems to be complicated the one you told..

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome and Safari you can add the following in your CSS:

```
@media print
{
    * {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
}
```